# JavaFX getting the primaryStage (Main Menu) of my App

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to implement an App with JavaFX and SceneBuilder.

I made a Main menu with different buttons, and each button leads to a different page.

So for example, when I click the first button, i want that i switch to a new panel and then, if I want to go back to the previous panel, I have just to click on "Back"-Button on the 2nd panel that I got.

The 1st step, to have a new page when I click on the buttons, is okay. Now the problem is in implementing the "Back" Button. I want to click on it, and have the previous panel, but I dont find a solution for that.

Here is the code:

start method of my App (OrderCheck.java)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("OrderCheck.fxml"));
    Pane myPane = (Pane)myLoader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Main Menu");
    OrderCheckController controller = (OrderCheckController) myLoader.getController();
    controller.setPrevStage(primaryStage);
    Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);        
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

example of the onAction of 1 button on the main panel: (OrderCheckController.java):

```
public void personalButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
   Stage stage = new Stage();
   stage.setTitle("Personal Menu");
   AnchorPane myPane = null;
   myPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Personal.fxml"));
   Scene scene = new Scene(myPane);
   stage.setScene(scene);

   prevStage.close();

   stage.show();
}
```

Example of implementation of the Back-Button in the new view, when that button is clicked (PersonalController.java):

```
public void backButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stage stageTheLabelBelongs = (Stage) backButton.getScene().getWindow();
    setPrevStage(stageTheLabelBelongs);
    prevStage.close();
    stageTheLabelBelongs.show();
 }
```

the method setPrevStage(Stage stage) is implemented in both Controllers (OrderCheckController and PersonalController)

```
public void setPrevStage(Stage stage){
     this.prevStage = stage;
}
```

So now when I click on the "Back"-button on the new page that i get, the window will be fast closed and opened-up again as nothing happened.

Comment: Juggling `Stages` seems like a heavy handed approach for what you're trying to do. Is there a reason you want to use multiple `Stages` instead of managing a `List<>` of `Nodes`, `Panes`, `Parents`, etc?

Comment: Have you seen the login demo from Oracles FX Demo and Samples? There the Main class shows how to replace the scene content with a different stage/FXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this. I refer to the primary stage this way in my app.

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

public static Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    stage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    primaryStage = stage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

And from your other controllers you can access it using `JavaFXApplication.primaryStage`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Main class like user Sudip Saha then just make method goBack() in controller where you are using Back button.

goBack() method:

```
public void goBack() {
    BorderPane mainScreen;
    try {
        mainScreen = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(JavaFXApplication.class .getResource("../javafx/main.fxml"));
        JavaFXApplication.setCenterPane(mainScreen); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

After that just call goBack() method in "Back" button in Scene Builder